# CSS background images won't load after form submit

Tags: javascript, extjs, internet-explorer-9, extjs3

I have a search form that, once submitted loads the results of the search query on a new page. When you press submit, however, it takes about 10 seconds or so before the next page is rendered, so I'm showing a loading box (via ExtJS) while the user waits for the next page to load.

The problem is in IE9, the border, which uses background images, isn't showing up on the loading box.

I've done some digging around, and I've concluded that for some reason IE9 will not load any of the images specified in the CSS after the form has been submitted (and the next page has begun to load).

If I use the following code to set a timeout of 200 milliseconds before the form is submitted, everything loads fine.

```
function() {    
    Ext.MessageBox.wait('Searching for tenants eligible for rent increase...', 'Searching');
    setTimeout(function() { document.getElementById('rental_increase_form').submit(); }, 200);
    return false;
}
```

**So here's my questions:**

Can anyone else confirm that IE9 does not load CSS images on the current page after the next page request has begun? Is this a bug or intended functionality? Can anyone suggest a solution that doesn't involve setting a timeout before submitting a form? That solution seems a little hackish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't have IE here to confirm, but can you just pre-load these images on start of the first page? E.g. make a set of hidden elements that have these background images set in their CSS. That way, you'll have the images loaded and when you show the loading box. Don't know if that is the only issue, though, but you can try to see if it works.

Comment: Thanks icyrock.com, I was aware that I could do this, but it's not really a good solution because I'm using ExtJS. It actually defeats the purpose of using a library like that if I have to manually preload some of its elements myself.

Comment: I guess in this case it's more of a feature of ExtJS in combination with IE9. Unfortunately, I don't see other options. From what you say, it seems IE9 forbids loading after form submit, so your only option is to load images before that. So either the timeout solution you already found or "fixing" the library by preloading images. I agree both are hacky, but I find them rather localized if that is a metric you are willing to go by.

Comment: Check this link, too, for a similar issue: http://www.sencha.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-142127.html?s=c9b8a7cc2447101aeb2fb20db4d0f11f. Do you have an option to try different (e.g. previous) versions of ExtJS? This might confirm whether it's ExtJS or IE9 issue.

Comment: Haha, yes that was a coworker of mine working on this same bug. Thanks anyway. I'm hoping someone can confirm whether or not this is intended functionality of IE9 or if it's just a random bug.

Comment: It's seems it is IE9: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5956106/ie9-submit-time-css-repainting. Note it's a different library, jQuery in this case. Unless it's your co-worker again ;)

Comment: Thanks! That link was very helpful. It seems this is indeed an IE9 issue.